# Swift dynamictype initialisation with dynamic protocol type

Tags: swift, struct, protocols, dynamictype, associated-types

I have a number of structs which implement a `Resource` protocol. This defines that they must have a variable `extendedInfo` which conforms to `ExtendedInfo` protocol to provide a way to initialise them with json via `init(json: [String: AnyObject]`. I'm trying to provide a way to dynamically instantiate these, with JSON, providing the right type of `ExtendedInfo` and assign it to the struct's `extendedInfo` variable. However, I'm getting a `Argument labels '(json:)' do not match any available overloads` error when trying to instantiate them via their `dynamicType`

```
protocol Resource {

    associatedtype ExtendedInfoTypeAlias: ExtendedInfo

    var extendedInfo: ExtendedInfoTypeAlias? { get set }
}

protocol ExtendedInfo {
    init(json: [String: AnyObject])
}

struct User: Resource {

    typealias ExtendedInfoTypeAlias = UserExtendedInfo

    let name: String = "Name"
    var extendedInfo: UserExtendedInfo?
}

struct UserExtendedInfo: ExtendedInfo {

    let age: Int?

    init(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        age = json["age"] as? Int
    }
}


let user = User()
let sampleJSON = ["age": 50]

let userExtendedInfo = user.extendedInfo.dynamicType.init(json: sampleJSON) // Argument labels '(json:)' do not match any available overloads
user.extendedInfo = userExtendedInfo
```

Any ideas guys? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to explicitly define the type of `ExtendedInfoTypeAlias` in your struct implementation – you can just let it be inferred by the type you provide for `extendedInfo`.

```
struct User: Resource {
    let name: String = "Name"
    var extendedInfo: UserExtendedInfo?
}
```

Second of all, you can just use the protocol's associated type of your given struct's `dynamicType` in order to use your given initialiser. For example:

```
user.extendedInfo = user.dynamicType.ExtendedInfoTypeAlias.init(json: sampleJSON)
print(user.extendedInfo) // Optional(Dynamic_Protocols.UserExtendedInfo(age: Optional(50)))
```

As for why your current code doesn't work, I suspect it's due to the fact that you're getting the `dynamicType` from an optional – which is preventing you from calling your initialiser on it.

---

<del>I did find that the following works, even when `extendedInfo` is `nil`</del>. ([This is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824048/why-does-using-dynamictype-on-a-force-unwrapped-optional-struct-not-crash)).

<del>`user.extendedInfo = user.extendedInfo!.dynamicType.init(json: sampleJSON)`</del>

Comment: @trundrumbalind Happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
let user = User()
```

To:

```
var user = User()
```

and try this:

```
user.extendedInfo = UserExtendedInfo(json: sampleJSON)
```

Comment: The idea is that I don't explicitly say which `...ExtendedInfo` object I want to initialise. I want to be able to infer which one from the type of the type of the `extendedInfo` variable so that it can work with any object which adheres to the `Resource` protocol.