# Why does using dynamicType on a force unwrapped nil optional value type work?

Tags: swift

I was really confused to find that the following code simply refuses to crash with the typical “*Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*” exception that you’d expect from force unwrapping `bar`.

```
struct Foo {
    var bar: Bar?
}
struct Bar {}

var foo = Foo()

debugPrint(foo.bar) // nil
debugPrint(foo.bar!.dynamicType) // _dynamicType.Bar
```

It seems `dynamicType` is *somehow* able to fallback to the defined type of `bar` – without crashing.

Note this only appears to happen when `Bar` is defined as a *value* type (as [@dfri says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824048/why-does-using-dynamictype-on-a-force-unwrapped-optional-struct-not-crash#comment61221761_36824048)), `Foo` is a `struct` or `final class` (as [pointed out by @MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824048/why-does-using-dynamictype-on-a-force-unwrapped-optional-struct-not-crash#comment61219783_36824048)) & `foo` is mutable.

I did initially consider that it could just be a compiler optimisation due to the fact that the type of `bar` is known at compile time, so therefore the force unwrapping could have been optimised away – but it also crashes when `Bar` is defined as a `final class`. Furthermore, if I set the "Optimisation Level" to `-Onone`, it still works.

I’m inclined to think this is a weird bug, but would like some confirmation.

Is this a bug or a feature with `dynamicType`, or am I simply missing something here?

<sub>(Using Xcode 7.3 w/ Swift 2.2)</sub>

---

#### Swift 4.0.3 update

This is still reproducible (with an even more minimal example) in Swift 4.0.3:

```
var foo: String?
print(type(of: foo!)) // String
```

Here we're using `dynamicType`'s successor, `type(of:)`, to get the dynamic type; and like the previous example, it doesn't crash.

Comment: Note that it crashes with `class Foo`, but *not* with `final class Foo` ... :)

Comment: You are speaking about cases when the result of `dynamicType` is known at compile time. It could be a bug with that `!`.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the same thing that makes pattern matching work - that probably sounded stupid but I mean, it is able to use the hint `final` like a `sealed` and work backwards... it smells like unintended behavior to me but wth do i know :)

Comment: @Sulthan I did consider that it could just be a compiler optimisation due to the fact that the type of `bar` is known at compile time, so therefore the force unwrapping could have been optimised away – but it crashes when `Bar` is defined as a `final class`, so I'm not so sure!

Comment: It seems as if one key for allowing the above to run without a runtime exception is that `bar` is _any kind of value_ type, not just a struct or an enum (and `foo` is a mutable). E.g. `struct Foo { var bar: Int? }; var foo = Foo()` similarily allows using `dynamicType` on the forcibly unwrapped (empty) optional `foo.bar` (whereas e.g. `bar` as foundation:s `NSNumber` reference type will yield a crash).

Comment: @dfri Another good point! I have edited OP with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [indeed a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1327), which has been fixed [by this pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/14410), which should make it into the release of Swift 4.2, all things going well.

---

If anyone’s interested in the seemingly bizarre requirements to reproduce it, here’s a (not really) brief overview on what was happening...

Calls to the standard library function `type(of:)` are resolved as a special case by the type-checker; they’re replaced in the AST by a special “dynamic type expression“. I didn't investigate how it's predecessor `dynamicType` was handled, but I suspect it did something similar.

When emitting an intermediate representation (SIL to be specific) for a such an expression, [the compiler checks to see](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/34e77c0f258a989fd800d4b471d136fc11151558/lib/SILGen/SILGenExpr.cpp#L2846) if the resulting metatype is “thick” (for class and protocol-typed instances), and if so emits the sub-expression (i.e the argument passed) and gets its dynamic type.

*However*, if the resulting metatype is “thin” (for structs and enums), the compiler knows the metatype value at compile time. Therefore the sub-expression only needs to be evaluated if it has side effects. Such an expression is emitted as an “ignored expression”.

The problem was with the logic in emitting ignored expressions that were also lvalues (an expression that can be assigned to and passed as `inout`).

Swift lvalues can be made up of multiple components (for example, accessing a property, performing a force unwrap, etc.). Some components are “physical”, meaning that they produce an address to work with, and other components are “logical”, meaning that they comprise of a getter and setter (just like computed variables).

The problem was that *physical* components were incorrectly assumed to be side-effect free; however force unwrapping is a physical component and is *not* side effect free (a key-path expression is also a non-pure physical component).

So ignored expression lvalues with force unwrap components will incorrectly not evaluate the force unwrapping if they’re only made up of physical components.

Let’s take a look at a couple of cases that currently crash (in Swift 4.0.3), and explain why the bug was side-stepped and the force unwrap was correctly evaluated:

```
let foo: String? = nil
print(type(of: foo!)) // crash!
```

Here, `foo` is not an lvalue (as it’s declared `let`), so we just get its value and force unwrap.

```
class C {} // also crashes if 'C' is 'final', the metatype is still "thick"
var foo: C? = nil
let x = type(of: foo!) // crash!
```

Here, `foo` *is* an lvalue, but the compiler sees that the resulting metatype is “thick”, and so depends on the value of `foo!`, so the lvalue is loaded, and the force unwrap is therefore evaluated.

Let’s also take a look at this interesting case:

```
class Foo {
  var bar: Bar?
}
struct Bar {}

var foo = Foo()
print(type(of: foo.bar!)) // crash!
```

It crashes, but it won’t if `Foo` is marked as `final`. The resulting metatype is “thin” either way, so what difference does `Foo` being `final` make?

Well, when `Foo` is non-final, the compiler cannot just refer to the property `bar` by address, as it may be overridden by a subclass, which may well re-implement it as a computed property.   So, the lvalue will contain a *logical* component (the call to `bar`’s getter), therefore the compiler will perform a load to ensure the potential side effects of this getter call are evaluated (and the force unwrap will also be evaluated in the load).

However when `Foo` is `final`, the property access to `bar` can be modelled as a physical component, i.e it can be referred to by address. Therefore the compiler incorrectly assumed that because all the lvalue's components are physical, it could skip evaluating it.

Anyway, this issue is fixed now. Hopefully someone finds the above ramble useful and/or interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

Because dynamicType operates on types, not values. At runtime ...

```
foo.bar.dynamicType == Swift.Optional<Bar>
```

So naturally, when you you unwrap the optional, you get `Bar`

Comment: `dynamicType` most definitely operates on values, otherwise it's not dynamic! You are right in that the dynamic type of `foo.bar` is `Swift.Optional<Bar>` – but I'm trying to get the dynamic type of `foo.bar!` here. As `foo.bar` is a `Swift.Optional<Bar>.None`, even if the type information of `bar` is somehow inffered after force unwrapping (which it appears to be), that doesn't answer *how* it's able to avoid the fatal error that should have occured when force unwrapping a `.None` optional in the first place.